# How can I disavow or remove Redirected spam site link

Tags: backlinks, disavow-links

I am facing a problem that some redirected spam site linked to my domain. Now my domain spam increased to near 41%.  I have submitted disavow request few times, Still getting the same result. Can't fix it. What should I do now?

Comment: How are you measuring "domain spam"?    What does it even mean that it is "near 41%"?

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the steps laid out by [Google](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2648487?hl=en) - see here.

Comment: Answers that consist only of a link are not very helpful.   Linked documents often change over time or go missing altogether.  In any case, it is annoying to have to click to get an answer rather than just read it here.   It is far better to write a full answer here and provide links for reference and further reading.

Comment: It is the official document by Google, and the beauty is - Google will update the document accordingly, so with a link the person will always be given the latest way of implementing it. If I on the other hand copy and paste the soliton offered at a time - it may not be correct a few month later. And we all know that Google changes their page layouts, naming, conventions, etc. Constantly

Comment: So in a way - I thought this well through having posted a link. Way more dynamic, clean and efficient (any OO developer would agree) - hip hip, hurray, George saved the day !!

Comment: For the most part, your answers here are excellent.   Many new users don't know our policies on link only answer and signatures.   We are trying to build a repository of answers without much fluff.   In the case of signatures, they get in the way of the answers.  In the case of links, they are not enough answer.   Even Google has a history of taking help documents down on occasion.